# How to check the equality of strings in clojure without invoking java.lang.String?

Tags: clojure

Is there any way in clojure to check the equality of strings?
i.e. I need to know, whether their contents is equal, not location.

thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Equality in Clojure (the `=` function) always tests value, not identity, so two strings are `=` if they have the same contents.

For most Java types, including String, Clojure `=` dispatches to Java `.equals`. [String.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is defined as "represents the same sequence of characters."

If you want to test identity (Are these pointers to the same location in memory?) use the `identical?` function.

Comment: I need to compare a security token, so I need a function that check if the content is exactly the same and don't accept wildcards or regex expressions. Do you know if the = function of clojure satisfies my need or I need a more specific function?

Comment: Clojure `=` does not use wildcards or regular expressions.

Answer (score 9):

```
(= "hello" (str "hel" "lo"))
; => true
```

The JVM has a string pool that holds at most one entry per value, so identity and value equality are the same comparison. There are ways using `StringBuilder.` and `String.` where this is not strictly true, but because the clojure equality function calls `.equals`, a value comparison will be performed if the identities are different.

Comment: `(identical? "hello" (str "hel" "lo"))` is false. Java's pool of interned strings is only for strings which are constants. So `(identical? "hello" "hello")` is true, but as soon as you compute some string it won't be pointer-equal to any others. You can force lookup/storage in the pool with `(identical? "hello" (.intern (str "hel" "lo")))` (true)