# Clojure: Why = and .equals on strings have different performance?

Tags: string, performance, clojure

I am relative new to Clojure and have a following simple function

```
(defn find-func
[what seq]
   (filter #(.equals what %) seq)
)
```

I noticed that the above function is significantly slower than when I substitute .equals with = like this:

```
(defn find-func
[what seq]
   (filter #(= what %) seq)
)
```

I observed it when I ran it from REPL on jdk 1.8.0_25, clojure 1.8:

```
(find-func "10" (map str (range 0 800000)))
```

Why is that so? I though from another stackoverflow answer ([Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337924/how-to-check-the-equality-of-strings-in-clojure-without-invoking-java-lang-strin)) that = calls .equals so that should not have any performance difference. Has that been optimized from that time? Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: Most likely very connected. I just found out that the same performance difference applies to (.endsWith what %) and (clojure.string.ends-with? what %)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your first `find-func` uses reflection, whereas your second one doesn't:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn find-func [what seq]
  (filter #(.equals what %) seq))
;; Reflection warning, foo.clj:2:12 - call to method equals can't be resolved (target class is unknown).

(defn find-func [what seq]
  (filter #(= what %) seq))
```

If you add a type hint to avoid the reflection, `.equals` will be faster than `=`:

```
(defn find-func [^Object what seq]
  (filter #(.equals what %) seq))
```

Clojure should be able to figure this out on its own, but for some reason it doesn't.